# how to kill dovecot processes

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill

I've installed dovecot on my Ubuntu 14.04 but not able to get it work. Nevertheless when I used `nmap` to check its processes I noticed there are processes like pop3, imap, pop3s, imap3, pptp running.

I wanted to kill these processes and tried `kill -9 dovecot`, `killall -9 dovecot`, `doveadm stop`. But dovecot is restarted immediately after every command is executed.

How can I effectively stop dovecot service and purge the whole package from my Ubuntu? (for the 2nd part I guess I can use `apt-get purge`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo service dovecot stop
```

And to completely remove dovecot:

```
sudo apt-get remove dovecot-imapd
```

Comment: Worth the operations should be performed essentially in this order.

Comment: thanks. I didn't find script dovecot under /etc/init.d, but i did manage to stop it by running sudo service dovecot stop